# handle multilayer json array in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a simple array that I am trying to handle. It consists of two parts. A group of `vid_ids` and a single element called `page`. I was initially using a for loop to go through just the vid_id array but now since I added the `page` element I am not quite sure how to handle it. Anyone have any ideas

**PHP**

```
$array=array();
$sql = 'SELECT * from video LIMIT 0,9';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $array[]=htmlspecialchars( $row['vid_id'], ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
}
$data['vid_array']=$array;
$data['page']=1;
$out = json_encode($data);
print $out;
```

**Javascript**

```
$.getJSON("load_live.php?t=" + (new Date()), function(json) {  
    for(vid_array.i=0; i < json.length; vid_array.i++) {
        $('#element').append('<div id="'+json.vid_array[i]+'"></div>');
    }
    $('#element').append(json.page);
});
```

**Json Output**

> {"vid_array":["3si7bxwk8ftpnvsw1gcf6giyxxch46sn","jch0dfepnu9hn0uw3m283g429mcj63q6","arh3xeklxjlztffxtybnucfnzosetgr8","6duy7xxj274w2cmhauth1tj933ck5i6z","9xx6pefa52s38ez77s5nbhz6jywbohc6","4eslxxl4etj5smhhr3wymc6pr8kys10c","4db1hp47be4auel633okbg6l884u0ef5","incwb9juxug8h986r9xt738ru4n0camd","vmsoqx03vppflh646b3au6jrlzt6mkej"],"page":1}

Comment: With `ENT_NOQUOTES` specified, you're not escaping quotes so when you embed the content inside an attribute, then you've got a persistant XSS vulnerability.  I can execute arbitrary script by persisting a payload like `" onclick="alert(1337)" bogus="`.  To fix, remove the `ENT_NOQUOTES` from the call to `htmlspecialchars`.  From the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), "`'"'` (double quote) becomes `'&quot;'` when `ENT_NOQUOTES` is **not** set."

Comment: Thanks buddy. I will address that.

Comment: What's not working now? I think all you have to change is `json.length` to `json.vid_array.length`. Everything else looks good.

Comment: I'd remove the `htmlspecialchars()` call entirely. It really has no place there. `json_encode()` will deal with any problem characters in values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your JavaScript for-loop is a little off. Try this

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.vid_array.length; i++) {
    $('<div>').attr('id', json.vid_array[i]).appendTo('#element');
}
```

Also, as mentioned in my comment, you don't need to use `htmlspecialchars()` there. Simply assign the `vid_id` value to the array

```
$array[] = $row['vid_id'];
```

Comment: Thanks Phil. I thought htmlspecialchars was really important for escaping output?

Comment: @Scarface You aren't displaying anything at that stage though. `json_encode()` handles converting your data to a client-side friendly format. Using the `attr()` method as shown in my answer should give you better mileage than concatenation

Comment: @Scarface What I mean by that is the `attr()` method automatically encodes problem characters whereas your original concatenation method would not

Comment: Thanks alot Phil. Appreciate your time and help.